# React Native build Error (AccessibilityInfo does not Exist)

Tags: react-native

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `E:\react-apps\Whatsapp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map

Comment: what is your react native version?

Comment: 0.44.0
"dependencies": {
    "autosuggest": "0.0.2",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.44.0",

Comment: try changing your react-native version from package.json file from "^0.44.0" to "0.55.4".

Answer (score 0):

As you have react-native version "0.44.0" and react with version "16.3.1", as per the document you must have correct versions dependencies. Please upgrade your react native version.
Please refer this link for more details https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md

remove node_modules folder from your project. Also use below commands:

```
npm prune
npm cache clear
npm cache clean --force
npm start -- --reset-cache
npm i
```

Comment: after downgrading to 0.55.4, i am getting following error using command react-native run-android :
bundling failed: Error: Plugin 0 specified in "\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-native\\index.js" provided an invalid property of "default" (While processing preset: "node_modules\\babel-preset-react-native\\index.js")

Comment: @Amit Sharma, I have modified the answer, please check the same.

Comment: I  ran all commands provided by you but still facing same issue AccessibilityInfo 
error ,Even i am tring to create new project simply using react-native init projectname ,after running the newly created project facing same error

Comment: try changing your react-native version from package.json file from "^0.44.0" to "0.55.4"